# Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'Not Found Error'

Tags: domdocument, php

Bascially I'm writing a templating system for my CMS and I want to have a modular structure which involves people putting in tags like:

`<module name="news" />` or `<include name="anotherTemplateFile" />` which I then want to find in my php and replace with dynamic html.

Someone on here pointed me towards DOMDocument, but I've already come across a problem.

I'm trying to find all `<include />` tags in my template and replace them with some simple html. Here is my template code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>CMS</title>
<include name="head" />
</head>

<body>

<include name="header" />

<include name="content" />

<include name="footer" />

</body>
</html>
```

And here is my PHP:

```
$template = new DOMDocument();
$template->load("template/template.tpl");

foreach( $template->getElementsByTagName("include") as $include ) {
    $element = '<input type="text" value="'.print_r($include, true).'" />';
    $output = $template->createTextNode($element);
    $template->replaceChild($output, $include);
}

echo $template->saveHTML();
```

Now, I get the fatal error `Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'Not Found Error'`.

I've looked this up and it seems to be that because my `<include />` tags aren't necessarily DIRECT children of `$template` its not replacing them.

How can I replace them independently of descent?

Thank you

Tom

**EDIT**

Basically I had a brainwave of sorts. If I do something like this for my PHP I see its trying to do what I want it to do:

```
$template = new DOMDocument();
    $template->load("template/template.tpl");

    foreach( $template->getElementsByTagName("include") as $include ) {
        $element = '<input type="text" value="'.print_r($include, true).'" />';
        $output = $template->createTextNode($element);
        // this line is different:
        $include->parentNode->replaceChild($output, $include);
    }

    echo $template->saveHTML();
```

However it only seems to change 1 occurence in the `<body>` of my HTML... when I have 3. :/

Comment: try http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ instead of DOMDocument

Comment: @yoda you are telling him to use a dull butter knife instead of a scalpell

Comment: simplehtmldom eats memmory like nothing I have ever seen

Comment: @Thomas your code wont work because `createTextNode()` will escape any angle brackets. Use [`appendXML()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/domdocumentfragment.appendxml.php) instead

Comment: thanks gordon. :) would have stumbled at that hurdle then. however for now the problem is that it's not replacing them at all...

Comment: hey, I edited my question with an update. :)

Comment: That's the first time I've ever seen memmory spelled with two `m`s.  Sort of like the first time someone says, "I always wear googles when I swim."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem with your DOMDocument->load, try

```
$template->loadHTMLFile("template/template.tpl");
```

But you may need to give it a .html extension.

this is looking for a html or an xml file. also, whenever you are using DOMDocument with html it is a good idea to use `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);` before the load call.

OKAY THIS WORKS:

```
foreach( $template->getElementsByTagName("include") as $include ) {
     if ($include->hasAttributes()) {
     $includes[] = $include;
     }
     //var_dump($includes);
 }
 foreach ($includes as $include) {
            $include_name = $include->getAttribute("name");
        $input = $template->createElement('input');
$type = $template->createAttribute('type');
$typeval = $template->createTextNode('text');
$type->appendChild($typeval);
$input->appendChild($type);
$name = $template->createAttribute('name');
$nameval = $template->createTextNode('the_name');
$name->appendChild($nameval);
$input->appendChild($name);
$value = $template->createAttribute('value');
$valueval = $template->createTextNode($include_name);
$value->appendChild($valueval);
$input->appendChild($value);
if ($include->getAttribute("name") == "head") {
       $template->getElementsByTagName('head')->item(0)->replaceChild($input,$include);
}
else {
        $template->getElementsByTagName("body")->item(0)->replaceChild($input,$include);
}
        }
        //$template->load($nht);
        echo $template->saveHTML();
```

Comment: ah, all those ideas will be good, thank you, however none of them work. I've edited my original question with an update if you could have a look please? Basically instead of $template->replaceChild I used $include->parentNode->replaceChild which works, however only changes 1 instance of the search. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Thomas I have posted an update that works, but I also agree with Bobince, there are far better ways to do what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

> However it only seems to change 1 occurence in the  of my HTML... when I have 3. :/

DOM NodeLists are ‘live’: when you remove an `<include>` element from the document (by replacing it), it disappears from the list. Conversely if you add a new `<include>` into the document, it will appear in your list.

You might expect this for a NodeList that comes from an element's `childNodes`, but the same is true of NodeLists that are returned `getElementsByTagName`. It's part of the W3C DOM standard and occurs in web browsers' DOMs as well as PHP's DOMDocument.

So what you have here is a destructive iteration. Remove the first `<include>` (item 0 in the list) and the second `<include>`, previously item 1, become the new item 0. Now when you move on to the next item in the list, item 1 is what used to be item 2, causing you to only look at half the items.

PHP's `foreach` loop looks like it might protect you from that, but actually under the covers it's doing exactly the same as a traditional indexed `for` loop.

I'd try to avoid creating a new templating language for PHP; there are already so many, not to mention PHP itself. Creating one out of DOMDocument is also going to be especially slow.

eta: In general regex replace would be faster, assuming a simple match pattern that doesn't introduce loads of backtracking. However if you are wedded to an XML syntax, regex isn't very good at parsing that. But what are you attempting to do, that can't already be done with PHP?

```
<?php function write_header() { ?>
    <p>This is the header bit!</p>
<? } ?>

<body>
    ...
    <?php write_header(); ?>
    ...
</body>
```

Comment: @thomas-clayson I agree, while my updated answer below works, the amount of code needed to such things as you are talking about in DomDocument will quickly get ludicrous. If I have ever had to do my own templates I have used SECTION_NAME and then $template = str_replace("SECTION_NAME",$replacement,$template);

Comment: hi bobince, I'm not really trying to create a templating language as such, just a quick and easy way to make websites that dosen't involve large code changes each time! Liam, would preg_replace_callback be faster than using dom document?

Comment: I am trying to completely divorce the php from the HTML. Pure MVC as it were. I don't want to have to trawl through code just to add or remove constructs. Some of the "modules" we'll be creating will be incredibly complex and I'd rather have them completely removed from the layout/HTML so they're self contained as it were.

Comment: @thomas That is still what will be achieved using Bobince's way (a method I have used many times) as long as you put the php in a seperate files i.e. modules.php or functions.php. Anyway, if you are set on this, did you get my method below working?

Comment: oh yeah, sorry - the solution, gleaned from your example, was to iterate through each 'item' in the node list. :) So I'll mark your answer right. However I've decided to pursue a different method now, given that this way seems rather more difficult than just using a simple preg_replace. :) Thank you for all your input though, I've learnt so much. :)