# Replace Tag in HTML with DOMDocument

Tags: php, dom

I'm trying to edit html tags with DOMDocument::loadHTML in php. The html data is a part of html and not the whole page. I followed what this page ([PHP - DOMDocument - need to change/replace an existing HTML tag w/ a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824503/php-domdocument-need-to-change-replace-an-existing-html-tag-w-a-new-one)) says.

This should convert pre tags into div tags but it gives "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'Not Found Error'."

```
<?php
$contents = <<<STR
<pre>hi</pre>
<pre>hello</pre>
<pre>bye</pre>
STR;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($contents);

foreach( $dom->getElementsByTagName("pre") as $nodePre ) {
    $nodeDiv = $dom->createElement("div", $nodePre->nodeValue);
    $dom->replaceChild($nodeDiv, $nodePre);
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
?>
```

[Edit]
While I'm trying to iterate the node object backwards, I get this error, 'Notice: Trying to get property of non-object...'

```
<?php
$contents = <<<STR
<pre>hi</pre>
<pre>hello</pre>
<pre>bye</pre>
STR;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($contents);
$domPre = $dom->getElementsByTagName('pre');
$length = $domPre->length;

    For ($i = $length; $i > -1 ; $i--) {
        $nodePre = $domPre->item($i);
        echo $nodePre->nodeValue . '<br />';
//      $nodeDiv = $dom->createElement("div", $nodePre->nodeValue);
//      $dom->replaceChild($nodeDiv, $nodePre);
    }

    // echo $dom->saveHTML();
?>
```

[Edit]
Okey, solved. Since the answered code has some error I post the solution here. Thanks all.

Solution:

```
<?php
$contents = <<<STR
<pre>hi</pre>
<pre>hello</pre>
<pre>bye</pre>
STR;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($contents);
$domPre = $dom->getElementsByTagName('pre');
$length = $domPre->length;

For ($i = $length - 1; $i > -1 ; $i--) {
    $nodePre = $domPre->item($i);
    $nodeDiv = $dom->createElement("div", $nodePre->nodeValue);
    $nodePre->parentNode->replaceChild($nodeDiv, $nodePre);
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
?>
```

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5284835/1233508).

Comment: I see so it is a problem of PHP. What about cloing the node and edit the cloned one? Is that slow compared to regex solutions?

Comment: It's not a problem of PHP. If you iterate over the NodeList backwards, you should be able to replace all the `pre` tags. If that doesn't work, change the logic to a less efficient version, replace first match, call `getElementsByTagName` again, replace first match...

Comment: Iterating backwars is a nice idea. I'll give it a try.

Comment: I updated the initial post. I got another error while trying to do your suggestion.

Comment: [`$length`: The number of nodes in the list. The range of valid child node indices is 0 to ***length - 1*** inclusive.](http://us.php.net/domNodeList)

Comment: I'm trying to get what you mean. I think I've already understood it but does that explain why the second example code in the updated initial post causes the error?

Comment: Ah, `For ($i = $length; $i > -1 ; $i--)` had to be For `($i = $length -1 ; $i > -1 ; $i--)`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is the call to `replaceChild()`. Rather than

```
$dom->replaceChild($nodeDiv, $nodePre);
```

use

```
$nodePre->parentNode->replaceChild($nodeDiv, $nodePre);
```

**update**

Here is a working code. Seems there is some issue with replacing multiple nodes (more info here: http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.replacechild.php) so you'll have to use a regressive loop to replace the elements.

```
$contents = <<<STR
<pre>hi</pre>
<pre>hello</pre>
<pre>bye</pre>
STR;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($contents);

$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName("pre");
for ($i = $elements->length - 1; $i >= 0; $i --) {
    $nodePre = $elements->item($i);
    $nodeDiv = $dom->createElement("div", $nodePre->nodeValue);
    $nodePre->parentNode->replaceChild($nodeDiv, $nodePre);
}
```

Comment: `<html><body><div>hi</div>
<pre>hello</pre>
<div>bye</div></body></html>` This is what I get by trying your suggestion. the second tag remains.

Comment: @Teno This problem seems to arise from trying to replace multiple nodes. There is a good advice from the PHP manual on how to get around this. Check my updated answer above.

Comment: The line `$nodePre = $elements->item($i);` causes the error, "Notice: Undefined variable: i". In spite of fixing the simple error by defining $i, it starts to say "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object."

Comment: @Teno kindly check again. that was supposedly a for loop. A well meaning editor changed it but did not do it thoroughly.

Answer (score 3):

Another way with [paquettg/php-html-parser](https://github.com/paquettg/php-html-parser) (didn't find the way to change name, so had to use hack with re-binding `$this`):

```
use PHPHtmlParser\Dom;
use PHPHtmlParser\Dom\HtmlNode;

$dom = new Dom;
$dom->load($text);
/** @var HtmlNode[] $tags */
foreach($dom->find('pre') as $tag) {
    $changeTag = function() {
        $this->name = 'div';
    };
    $changeTag->call($tag->tag);
};
echo (string)$dom;
```